# Error - Module 'FirebaseDatabase' has no member named 'database' in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have been getting a build time error that is preventing me from running my app in Xcode. I get the error - Module 'FirebaseDatabase' has no member named 'database'. And I also get the same error a few lines down but with storage. Error - Module 'FirebaseStorage' has no member named 'storage'.

```
    //Error Below - Module 'FirebaseDatabase' has no member named 'database'
let location = FirebaseDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(userUid)

    location.setValue(userData)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
func uploadImg() {
    if usernameField.text == nil {
        signUpBtn.isEnabled = false
    }  else {
            username = usernameField.text
            signUpBtn.isEnabled = true
    }
    guard let img = userImagePicker.image, imageSelected == true else {
        print("image needs to be selected")
        return
    }
    if let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.2) {
        let imgUid = NSUUID().uuidString
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"


//Error Below - Module 'FirebaseStorage' has no member named 'storage' 
FirebaseStorage.storage().reference().child(imgUid).putData(imgData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print ("did not upload image")
            } else {
                print("uploaded")
                let downlloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                if let url = downloadURL {
                    self.setUser(img: url)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FirebaseStorage.storage()
```

Should be

```
Storage.storage()
```

The same applies for FirebaseDatabase (Database).